# Is it valid to use div instead of form tag?

Tags: html, forms

I have a bunch of `<input type="text">`.Is it valid to put them in a `<div>` and not `<form>` ? I'm asking because I have `<button>`s there too, that need to do some functionality, and clicking on them causes jsfiddle's:

```
{"error": "Please use POST request"}
```

Adding `e.preventDefault()` fixes the problem, but I still wonder if replacing `<form>` with `<div>` is OK?
Thanks.

Comment: This will break the submit functionality in a browser, unless you are using a library like jQuery to submit the text to the server.

Comment: Do you even want a (submittable) form in the first place, or just buttons?

Comment: Thats fine - so you dont have a form just a bunch of buttons (and if you use jQuery to get the values from the inputs and submit the form its fine) - but $('xxx').serialize(); only works with forms

Comment: No, I don't want a submittable form. Im building a Quiz, people enter answers into <input>s, validation happens on the front-end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *valid* but violates the principles of [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), introduces accessibility issues and removes useful APIs.

Having a form:

- allows you to have a server side fallback for when the JavaScript fails.
- groups the form controls semantically (e.g. for the benefit of screen reader software).
- gives you access to `form.elements` and similar APIs for accessing controls simply (including for such things as jQuery's `serialize` method).